# How could I write the function for the card game, War, cleaner?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've been working on writing the card game war in `Unity` and somewere in the War function, I lose 2 cards. Is there any easier way of doing this, or could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
while(Flipped1[Flipped1.length-1].CardValue == Flipped2[Flipped2.length-1].CardValue)
{
    for(var i= 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //adds a card from the players hand to the flipped pile
        Flipped1.Add(playerOneCards[0]);
        Flipped2.Add(playerTwoCards[0]);

        //removes card from the array.
        playerOneCards.RemoveAt(0);
        playerTwoCards.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    p1War = Flipped1[Flipped1.length-1].img;
    p2War = Flipped2[Flipped2.length-1].img;

    Debug.Log(Flipped1[i].CardValue);
    Debug.Log(Flipped2[i].CardValue);

    Debug.Log(Flipped1[0].CardValue);
    Debug.Log(Flipped2[0].CardValue);

    if(Flipped1[i].CardValue < Flipped2[i].CardValue)
    {                                                           
        for(var j =0; j < Flipped1.length +2 || j < Flipped2.length+2; j++)
        {
            playerTwoCards.Add(Flipped1[0]);
            playerTwoCards.Add(Flipped2[0]);

            //removes card from the array.
            Flipped1.RemoveAt(0);
            Flipped2.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for(var q =0; q < Flipped1.length+2|| q < Flipped2.length+2; q++)
        {
            playerOneCards.Add(Flipped2[0]);
            playerOneCards.Add(Flipped1[0]);

            //removes card from the array.
            Flipped1.RemoveAt(0);
            Flipped2.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop iterates over `i`, and then closes. A few lines down, you do the if statement: `if(Flipped1[i].CardValue < Flipped2[i].CardValue)`. This isn't in the `for`loop anymore. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the logic in your for loop (inside the if/else).  You actually want to make that something like `while (Flipped1.length > 0)`, since what you're trying to do is empty the Flipped arrays, rather than effectively comparing it to an incrementing var less a constant.

Comment: after making that change i ended up with a Index is less then 0 or mor than or equal to the list count

Comment: Index?  What index?  you're just looping through the flipped list, pulling one off the bottom each time and adding it to the player cards list.  For that matter, if you didn't mind the order being a little different, you could just use a built-in concatenate function.  Also, I'm pretty sure you want to close your first while loop just before the if check.

Comment: thats what i was thinking i ended up figuring it out i had a loop running longer then i needed.